# Binary XML file line #12: Resource ID #0x7f0b0058 in android

Tags: android

Hi in the below code including another xml using this am setting tittle for toolbar.
For this crated textview name of the id is toolbar title.using this textview am setting actionbar title to "Home".but it is not working.

Logcat is showing binary xml file error

can any one please help me

Navigation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/color_white">


    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/dynamic_frame">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/realmsbg">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="310dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_border">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="310dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/luminary_controll"
                android:background="@color/color_white">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/luminary"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/colorNatural"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:text="Luminary"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>



                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/controller"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:text="Controller"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                   android:id="@+id/all_luminary">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/color_white">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bulb"
                android:tint="@color/colorNatural"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ALL LUMINARIES"
                android:textColor="@color/colorNatural"
                android:id="@+id/luminarie"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/color_green">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/bulb"
                    android:tint="@color/color_white"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="LUMINARIES ON"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                    android:id="@+id/sensors"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@color/color_red"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/bulb"
                    android:tint="@color/color_white"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="LUMINARIES OFF"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                    android:id="@+id/drivers"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/color_gray">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/bulb"
                    android:tint="@color/color_white"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="LUMINARIES NOT"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                    android:id="@+id/lum_not"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="WORKING"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/color_white"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:id="@+id/all_controllers"
                        android:visibility="invisible">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="250dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center">
                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/bulb"
                                android:tint="@color/color_white"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Lora Controller"
                                android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                                android:id="@+id/lora_control"
                                android:textSize="15sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"/>
                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/bulb"
                                android:tint="@color/color_white"/>

                        </LinearLayout>


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="200dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:background="@drawable/layout_border">
                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:src="@drawable/bulb"
                                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                android:tint="@color/color_white"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Light1"
                                android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                                android:id="@+id/light1"
                                android:textSize="15sp" />


                        </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

toolbar_spinner.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/ActionBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_toolbar"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/height_toolbar"
    android:background="@color/colorNatural"
    tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource"
    android:name="com.deepshikha.lightingsystem.NavigationViewActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

abc.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_view);
                Gravity.CENTER);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        mTitle.setText("Home");
```

Comment: toolbar_spinner can you paste this xml?

Comment: Are you trying to set text programatically to toolbar_title in java file? if yes. Then paste the java code also

Comment: Use the search feature in Android Studio to see what element `0x7f0b0058` refers to so you can quickly see where the error is

Comment: nothing to show

Comment: TextView mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        mTitle.setText("Home");
Try this

Comment: @No. not working

Comment: @Mohitpatel can you check it out

Comment: what is  it </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView> ?

Comment: Inside expanable listview am just defining a header as a log background

Answer (score 0):

You're seem trying to make a custom title in your ActionBar. Your code isn't working because you haven't hide the default title of the ActionBar. You can try the following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_view);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // you need to hide the default title of ActionBar
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    // Use current layout as the base View for findViewById instead of Toolbar.
    TextView tvTitle = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    tvTitle.setText("Home");

    ...
}
```

For the `Binary XML file line #12: Resource ID #0x7f0b0058` error. It's probably because you previously using `toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);`.

Try to commenting your layout then gradually uncommenting a block of layout to found the problem. Please have a look for [Divide-and-conquer algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm)